# Area of two triangles constructed by the diagonal of a trapezoid.

Tags: geometry

The area of a trapezoid, whose bases are in the ratio 3 to 2, equals 35.  Find the area of the triangles which we get if we draw one of the diagonals.

I have drawn in both diagonals and got a bunch of triangles and compared the areas. I got 35/3 and 70/3 but not sure that is correct.

Comment: The area of a triangle is $\frac{1}{2} b h$. The heights of your two triangles are the same, so the ratio of the bases is the ratio of the areas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $B$ be the great base and $b=2B/3$ be the small .

then the area of trapezoid is

$$A=\frac {b+B}{2}H=\frac {5}{6}BH =35$$ where $H $ is the height.

thus $$BH=42$$
the area of triangles are

> $$A_1=BH/2=21$$
>   and
>   $$A_2=2A_1/3=14$$

Answer (score 0):

A highly elementary way of "seeing" it:

[image]

By considering the common height and the ratio of the bases, we can conclude that the areas of triangles $ABD, ABC, ACD, BCD$ are in the ratio $3:3:2:2$. We can then decompose them into smaller triangles with areas in arbitrary units as indicated in the diagram.

So $5$ units equals $35$

$1$ unit equals $7$. And the required areas are $3$ units, or $21$ (for $ABD$ and $ABC$) and $2$ units or $14$ (for $ACD$ and $BCD$).

Trying to see things in an elementary way like this (avoiding symbolic algebra as far as possible) is highly encouraged by the new math syllabus for Primary school in Singapore (I sort of learnt this approach along with my son when I was coaching him).